# INFO: HTMLMANAGER: Sessions: Session action 'null' for web application '/api'

Tags: java, rest, session

'/api' is my restfull application deployed on tomcat. When I request rest call , it waits for long time to get response and gives : 502 error.  I saw the logmessage "INFO: HTMLMANAGER: Sessions: session action 'null' for web application '/api'" in log file. Any idea what is the problem ?